# Maven/Netbeans: open source files inside child modules

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, module

I have a multi-module maven project in this structure:

```
Parent
--ChildA
  --src
    --A.java
--ChildB
  --src
    --B.java
--ChildC
  --src
many more...
```

I have Parent open as a project in Netbeans, I want to be able to use "go to type" (ctrl+O) to quickly access A.java (due to the large amount of java files we cannot remember which module each java file resides).

Is there a way to do this? As of right now I cannot use ctrl+O to find the source files unless I have the child module open.

I am told it should work similar to: ctrl-O for A.java, Netbeans will alert me it is in ChildA and ask me if I want to open that module. Is there a special setting for this operation? or maybe something I can put in the parent POM?

Update: seems like there are no good solutions. I managed to get what I needed by creating a module that depended on all the other modules and was able to index and access all the sources that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way around that. Ctrl-O (or generally indexing of sources) is expensive and is done for opened projects only. There are large projects with hundreds of submodules, indexing them all all the time would require a lot of resources (CPU/memory/IO), limiting the scope to opened projects lets the user decide the scope of his work.
Some cheaper operations will still work (eg. hyperlinks).